# Close Dropdown when another Dropdown is opened

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a vertical sidebar nav menu with multiple buttons, each of which contains a dropdown of links. Clicking a button reveals a dropdown of anchor links in the nav menu (e.g. TF000120), and a div (e.g.'the forest') to the right of the nav menu in the main content area. Currently, if I click a button, its div and dropdown are both revealed fine. However if I click another button before closing the first, both sets of divs and dropdowns open. How would I make it so when another button is clicked, the currently open div and dropdown links are hidden again, before revealing the new div and dropdown links?

I used [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown_sidenav.asp) tutorial on W3.

HTML (Nav Menu)

```
<nav class="sidenav">
            <a href="#theforest" class="dropdown-btn" onclick="toggle_visibility('theforest');">The Forest
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-container">
                <a class="entry-num" href="#TF000120">[TF000120]</a>
                <a class="entry-num" href="#TF000220">[TF000220]</a>
                <a class="entry-num" href="#TF000320">[TF000320]</a>
            </div>
            <a href="#theocean" class="dropdown-btn" onclick="toggle_visibility('theocean');">The Ocean</a>
            <div class="dropdown-container" >
                <a class="entry-num" href="#TO000120">[TO000120]</a>
                <a class="entry-num" href="#TO000220">[TO000220]</a>
                <a class="entry-num" href="#TO000320">[TO000320]</a>
            </div>
            <a href="#thesky" class="dropdown-btn" onclick="toggle_visibility('thesky');">The Sky</a>
            <div class="dropdown-container" >
                <a class="entry-num" href="#TS000120">[TS000120]</a>
                <a class="entry-num" href="#TS000220">[TS000220]</a>
                <a class="entry-num" href="#TS000320">[TS000320]</a>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

JS

```
    <script>
        var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-btn");
        var i;

        for (i = 0; i < dropdown.length; i++) {
            dropdown[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
                this.classList.toggle("active");
                var dropdownContent = this.nextElementSibling;
                if (dropdownContent.style.display === "block") {
                    dropdownContent.style.display = "none";
                    } else {
                    dropdownContent.style.display = "block";
                    }
                });
            }
    </script>


<!--Toggle Function-->

  <script type="text/javascript">

    function toggle_visibility(id) {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       if(e.style.display == 'block')
          e.style.display = 'none';
       else
          e.style.display = 'block';
    }
</script>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

reset the style of all dropdowns on click, before you show the new one:

```
dropdown[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        //hide all divs that may be visible
        var lst = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-containder");
        for (var j = 0; j < lst.length; j++) { lst[j].style.display = "none";}

        //show the dive that the user selected
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var dropdownContent = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (dropdownContent.style.display === "block") {
            dropdownContent.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            dropdownContent.style.display = "block";
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! This worked to close the first button/hide dropdown and open the new button/show dropdown, but it still keeps both divs showing in the main content area. Also I can't minimise all buttons/dropdowns fully once one has been opened?

Comment: if there are other elements outside the html snippet that do not answer to the selector, you can add a class to those and update the selector. Note that all elements that correspond to that selector will be hidden.

Comment: can't get this working fully. not sure where i am going wrong. I think there must be a clash with the toggle visibility function or something

Comment: you are duplicating events. Remove the event listener that I used above, and move the two lines in  toggle_visibility